# 64 bit bsr asm is truncating the upper 32 bits

Tags: assembly, x86-64, lazarus, freepascal

I want bsr to operate on a 64 bit number. However, the following only works on the lower 32 bits of the input:

```
function BSR64(const Val: Int64): Integer;
begin
asm
  bsr           eax, [Val]   
...
```

How do I do this?

I'm compiling in 64 bit mode using Lazarus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the 64-bit register as follows:

```
 bsr rax, [val]
```

`eax` is the low 32-bits. `ax` is the low 16, and `al` is the low 8.

Using a 32-bit register destination implies a 32-bit operand size for memory.  BSR requires that they match, like pretty much every other instruction other than `movzx` and `movsx`.

Comment: That worked, thanks. But I have a misunderstanding, then. I thought the result is written into eax, so eax would be 0 to 63.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean here. The result is written to `eax`, but `eax` is the low 32 bits only (bits 0 to 31). I am not sure what your assembler will do in this case since `val` appears to be a 64-bit value, but my guess it that it truncates it copying only the low 32 bits of `[val]`.

Comment: I mean, the result of a bsr is 0 to 63 on a 64 bit input. I thought "0" to "63" is pushed into eax by the bsr op, meaning its range of only 6 bits easily fits into eax. So I thought that "0" to "63" is written into the dest, not that the dest has to match the source size.

Comment: @IanC: If you write to a 32-bit register in 64-bit mode you "destroy" the high part of the 64-bit register. From Intel: "32-bit operands generate a 32-bit result, **zero-extended** to a 64-bit result in the destination general-purpose
register."

Comment: It really is a different world to higher level coding. I wouldn't have naturally thought "Read 64 bit input, process, write 32 bit answer" would destroy the upper 32 bits of the input because the output is smaller. I'd need to learn a lot more to fully get why this is so.

Comment: @IanC it doesn't destroy the input, it just doesn't even read it. There is no version of `bsr` that reads 64bits and writes 32bits, both sizes have to be the same. Writing 32bits does destroy the high half of the output register.

Comment: Why not using the BsrQWord function: http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/bsrqword.html ?

Comment: in x86 only rotate through cl, movzx and movsx have src and dst of different sizes, in all other instructions all the parameters must have the same width. For the reason why writing to a 32-bit register destroy the high bits read [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137/995714)